# how to transfer xml data from java app to .net app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

i need to transfer xml data from my java web application to .net application.

like i transferred data from my application to other application.

```
public void send() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("URL:"+getUrl());
    System.out.println("Xml String:"+getConvertedString());
    String s1=getConvertedString().toString();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(getUrl()+"?xmldata1="+s1);
}
```

it will get url like url is http://localhost:8081/TransferXml/Kshitij

Kshitij is servlet and it will get reuest parameter and print on page.

just like that i need to pass on .net webservice and printing on page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is Construct url like http://urdotnetapp/...., append your parameters(xml) in url, and send request from Java web app to .net web service. As you provided your example, you can do the same with .net application. You can construct xml in .net web service.

Or you can do one more thing save your xml response from java application in xml file at shared location, Read that xml file from your dotnet application/web service.

Comment: but this request will be get and i want to make it post. how to do this?